# Self Adjoint operators and Normal operators.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this problem I am working on:

$H$ is an inner product space with inner product $(\cdot , \cdot)$ over a subfield of the complex numbers.

Suppose $T\in L(H,H)$ has an adjoint $T^*$.  Let R=$T+T^*$ and S=$T-T^*$.  I'm supposed to show that R and S are normal operators and that $T ∘T^*$ and $T^*∘T$ are self adjoint.

So for the first part, to show they are normal operators, this is what I have:

For $R$:
Need to show $(R(\alpha),\beta)=(\alpha,R(\beta))$
$$\implies ((T+T^*)(\alpha),\beta)=(T(\alpha)+(T^*(\alpha),(\beta))$$

$$=(T(\alpha),\beta)+(T^*(\alpha),\beta)$$

$$=(\alpha,T^*(\beta))+(\alpha,T(\beta))$$

$$=(\alpha,(T^*+T)(\beta))$$

$$=(\alpha,R(\beta))$$

I did something similar for $S$.  Did I show that they are normal operators or that they are self adjoint?  How do I show that $T \circ T^*$ and $T^*\circ T$ are self adjoint?  Thanks!

Comment: The identity $(R\alpha, \beta)=(\alpha, R\beta)$---equivalently, $R=R^*$---defines self-adjointness, not normality. Normality means $R\circ R^*=R^*\circ R$. Clearly, anything self-adjoint is normal.

Comment: So since I showed that R and S are self adjoint, would it be sufficient to say that since any self-adjoint is normal, then R and S are normal?

Comment: $S$ is not self-adjoint

Comment: For S I have that I need to show:
$(S(\alpha),\beta)=(\alpha,S(\beta)$
-->$((T-T^*)(\alpha),\beta)$=$(T(\alpha)-T^*(\alpha),(\beta))$

=$(T(\alpha),\beta)-(T^*(\alpha),\beta))$

=$(\alpha,T^*(\beta))-(\alpha,T(\beta))$

=$(\alpha,T^*(\beta))-(\alpha,T(\beta))$

=$(\alpha,T^*(\beta)-T(\beta))=(\alpha,(T^*-T)(\beta))$

=$(\alpha,S(\beta))$

Doesn't this show that S is self-adjoint?

Comment: No, it shows that $S^*=-S$.

Comment: Okay, so to show that R and S are normal to do I need to show that for R $(T+T^*)(T^*+T)=(T^*+T)(T+T^*)$, and similar for S? also, Do you have any suggestions as to how to show $T ∘T^*$ and $T^*∘T$ are self adjoint?